# How do I use WSO2 Identity Server to authenticate users from an existing database?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to authenticate users from an exiting database. Are there any examples of trivial Identity Providers to form a starting point?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the details from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager).

So in short, you will have to write a custom UserStoreManager in Java to customize the authentication logic.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great